# reactive messaging - ClassCastException cannot be cast to class io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi

Tags: java, mutiny, smallrye-reactive-messaging

```
@Incoming("from-processor-to-consumer")
public Multi<Void> consume(Multi<String> stream) {
    return stream.onItem()
            .invoke(msg -> {
                log.infof("consumer received %s", msg);
            })
            .onItem()
            .ignore();
}
```

When running this method raises the `ClassCastException`:

> `consume has thrown an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi`

Can I consume `Multi<String>` ?

Looking at the [SmallRye Reactive Messaging > Development Model > Consuming Payloads](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.13/model/model.html#consuming-payloads) it seems I can only consume one message at time.

Comment: what do you mean: end the Multi<String> ?

Comment: @Stultuske btw, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I must admit that the error message is useless and should be improved.

The problem is your application signature.

```java
@Incoming("from-processor-to-consumer")
@Outgoing("this-is-missing-in-your-code")
public Multi<Void> consume(Multi<String> stream) {
    return stream.onItem()
            .invoke(msg -> {
                log.infof("consumer received %s", msg);
            })
            .onItem()
            .ignore();
}
```

The `@Outgoing` annotation is missing. When returning a `Multi,` you need to say "where."

If your method is *terminal* (meaning is the final consumer), you cannot inject a `Multi`. The workaround is to use a simple no-op method:

```java
@Incoming("from-processor-to-consumer")
@Outgoing("this-is-missing-in-your-code")
public Multi<String> consume(Multi<String> stream) {
    return stream.onItem()
            .invoke(msg -> {
                log.infof("consumer received %s", msg);
            });
}


@Incoming("this-is-missing-in-your-code")
void noop(String s) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it made me clear that I really cannot have a method that is  *terminal*  and has a `Multi<something>` as param.